# Secondary developer access to phpMyAdmin with 1&1

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have managed hosting with 1&1. I know that 1&1 MySQL server administration isn't accessible outside their own phpMyAdmin, due to the databases sitting behind a pretty locked-down firewall, but I need to give an external developer access to import data to a MySQL database without:

1. Giving my administrative username/password.
2. Giving access to any of the files that are stored on my server (or risk breaking privacy laws)
3. Giving access to any of the other databases on the server (again - could risk breaking privacy laws)

So, the question is: is this possible with a 1&1 managed server? I'm of the opinion that it probably isn't, but I'd love to be proved wrong. Obviously the best option would be if there was a way to add a new sub-account which has limited access.

Comment: *"I know that 1&1 MySQL server administration isn't accessible outside their own phpMyAdmin"* - wrong because: if you cannot access the database with your own setup of phpMyAdmin, how should your website access the database? The question is, does 1&1 allow you another (restricted) MySQL user? The question is off-topic, because this is Stackoverflow, not 1&1.

Comment: Hi Dan, what I meant was that MySql Remote access is disabled by default for 1&1 managed servers. This doesn't mean that you can't connect to it through PHP. I also believe this isn't off topic, because a code-based solution or solution which uses other/external programming tools is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Then the question would be off-topic aswell because software/tool/library recommendations belong to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Maybe the easiest way would be to astk the 3rd party developer to send you the SQL by mail and you import them. From a security's aspect, I'd do it this way anyways, so you can double check the queries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install phpmyadmin from here: [http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home%5fpage/index.php)

Set up a user with access only to the database you want to give access to

Give the phpmyadmin install link to the other developer and give him the user/pass to access the only database you need to give access to.